# When writing to text file, around 4,000 values are not written

Tags: java, xml, arraylist

I've been trying to parse an XML file to store every node I need into an array/ArrayList; I've tried both. The parser is able to grab every value I want and store it into an array(list). I even printed the length after and it is exactly 262,144 values long(512*512). However, once I try to print this array to a text file, it always leaves around 3800 values missing. I have tried quite a few things to get this to work, but no matter how many values I try to store (even when trying an XML with only around 147,000 values) it STILL leaves out around 4000 values. Here's my parser/writer.

```
public class Reader 
{
private String path;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Document xmlDoc = getDocument("./src/porc.tmx");

    String fileName = "out.txt";
    String[] array = new String[262144];
    try
    {
        NodeList gidList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tile");
        for(int i = 0; i < gidList.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node g = gidList.item(i);
            if(g.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                Element gid = (Element) g;
                String id = gid.getAttribute("gid");
                array[i]=id;
            }
        }

        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
        for(int j = 0; j < 262144; j++)
        {
            outputStream.println(array[j]);
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Document getDocument(String docString)
{
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        factory.setValidating(false);

        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        return builder.parse(new InputSource(docString));
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is it always the last 3800 values that are missing?

Comment: I went through to check if the values were right, and it seems it's already left out values before 62,000. So I don't know where or why it's omitting the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you close the `outputStream` at the end of your processing.

```
PrintWriter outputStream = null;
try
{
    NodeList gidList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tile");
    for(int i = 0; i < gidList.getLength(); i++)
    {
        Node g = gidList.item(i);
        if(g.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        {
            Element gid = (Element) g;
            String id = gid.getAttribute("gid");
            array[i]=id;
        }
    }

    outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    for(int j = 0; j < 262144; j++)
    {
        outputStream.println(array[j]);
    }
}

catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    if (outputStream != null)
        outputStream.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to say.

Comment: Or use the [try-with-ressources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: @CosmicKidd You should move the declaration of that variable to be prior to the try block. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That leaves me with a NullPointerException at "outputStream.println(array[j]);".

Comment: @CosmicKidd Note that you should keep the `outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);` inside the try block.

Comment: It seems to have worked! If I may ask one more question, what was it I was doing wrong? What was happening beforehand exactly?

Comment: @CosmicKidd If you don't close the stream, some data that was buffered by the stream is never written to the output file.

Comment: That makes sense, although I thought it was writing to the file in every iteration of the for loop?

Comment: @CosmicKidd PrintWriter uses a BufferedWriter, which buffers the output, so it only writes to file when the buffer is full. Your can override this behavior by using the autoFlush flag in the constructor - `outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName,true)` - but that would slow down your program.